# Colorbox inside embedded html using jquery .load() weird behavior

Tags: jquery, inline, colorbox

I came across an interesting event while attempting to use colorbox jquery plugin.

First, to ensure that I was using the plugin properly I created a test page that loaded a div inline and it worked.

Next I migrated this code into my web site and found some weird display.

first i need to explain how i am loading the html:

I have a main index.htm page that has nav buttons. Each perform a jquery .load() which loads another html page inside the a content div.  The html that is loaded into the content div has the colorbox code and the div that loads up into colorbox.

```
Sample .load() used in nav button in index.htm:

//loads home.htm into contentdiv inside index.htm
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btHome").click(function (event) {
        $('#contentregion').load('home.htm');
    });

    return false;
});
```

When I call the color box function from within this embedded html page (home.htm) I just see nothing. I know the color box loaded because I cannot click any buttons or links anywhere on the whole page.

```
//function to load colorbox inline
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".HomeAccreditations").colorbox({ transition: "fade", speed: 500, overlayClose:         false, inline: true, href: "#AccredPopup", height: "500px", width: "500px"});
});
```

Next I tried the following. I loaded the index.html page as described before then navigated to a different embeded html using the nav buttons.

Next I returned back to index.html via the nav buttons. To  my surprise the colorbox modal now now shows up however i cannot click anywhere on the box as its just showing up like display only modal form.

Answer (score 1):

You may succeed using this:

```
$.colorbox({ transition: "fade", speed: 500, overlayClose: false, inline: true, href: "#AccredPopup", height: "500px", width: "500px"});
```